# How can I show the achievements while playing?

Tags: diep.io

I have been playing diep.io a lot since it has been recently updated, and they have added achievements. I want to look at these achievements when i am actively playing, so I can choose what I want to do next. I do not know how to do this. How do I?

Comment: What about haveing it open in a new tab?

Comment: Not using proxies, and I am prevented from opening multiple tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, unless you just got them. If you just got an achievement it will appear under the scoreboard or where it should be for a while. Otherwise, dying will show the menu screen so you can see them.